# Excel: Trying to get formula to populate value based on cell lookup across multiple tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hoping for some help. I have looked across forums and internet and can't seem to find anything to solve what I am trying to do.

**Problem**
I have 3 tables (or more) each of the same columns -> name, role, team

Separately I have a list of employee names, and a column beside it titled team.

What I am trying to do is cross reference the list against the 3 tables (or more), and for each match of name between the list and the tables, fill in the appropriate team name against the bottom list.

Please note a name may be in more than just one of the 3 tables. So in the list to be populated it would then display each of the approrpiate teams for which a match was found.

Have included an image of the problem in case the above does not make sense

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAkgU.png)

Appreciate any help

Comment: Use Power Query to create a Union of the tables.  Use `Filter` to the set of Teams for a given user.  Use `TextJoin`   to concatenate the result

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Textjoin + Vlookup function

In `C10`, array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IFERROR(CHOOSE({1,2,3},VLOOKUP(B10,B$2:D$5,3,0),VLOOKUP(B10,F$2:H$5,3,0),VLOOKUP(B10,J$2:L$5,3,0)),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use `INDEX` + `AGGREGATE`, which will extract the data in separate columns:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$L$5,2,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B15=$B$1:$L$5)*COLUMN($B$1:$L$5)+1;COLUMN()-COLUMN($B$15))),"")
```

According your sample, the command names must be the same in each individual table.

[image]